# jquery .not first or last

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

```
$('a').not(':first').not(':last').css('z-index', '90');
```

do this.

I'm having problem with this. any suggestion?

Comment: Really bad dewsciption of the problem: "I'm having problem with this".

Comment: where is the problem exactly. because for me it is working

Comment: try with this $('a:not(:first):not(:last)').css('z-index', '90');

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/baKYK/22/

Comment: this is my working fiddle, the non (first or last) doesn't show properly.

Comment: Did you know jQueryUI has [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)? Seems like you could save yourself some trouble and use something already written if the added overhead of including jQueryUI is not a problem.

Comment: $('.tabmenu a').not(':first').not(':last').hasClass('active')
is this wrong?

Comment: @andyb I know, but I having some conflicts with UI. I prefere to use less plug in as possible. Just need to fix this code above

Comment: Should all the tabs be visible underneath each other at all times? The initial page load, only _tab1_ is visible but if I click on the _Tab 1_ link the other tabs are visible at a lower `z-index`. What behaviour do you want?

Comment: @andyb should be the first tab on top the other with the others visible but underneath

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/baKYK/24/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it's *exactly* what you are after, but here we go...

I've cleaned up the code a fair bit and removed the parts that I thought were not relevant to the question, mainlyis the jQuery cookie code. I also optimized some other parts like the previous/next tab selection and the [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) manipulation

The *tab z-index* magic was in the end reduced to a <strike>very</strike> fairly simple function:

```
var i = 0;
$('.tab').css('z-index', function(index) {
    return index < selectedTabIndex ? 1 : (index > selectedTabIndex ? --i : 0);
});
```

This exploits the fact that the DOM has a natural z-index - elements further down the *page* that share the same z-index will obscure previous elements.

So given 3 tabs and you want to show the 3rd tab, the z-index can be equal for all elements and the natural z-index of the elements will mean that the 3rd tab will be on top.

It's probably best shown in a (badly drawn) matrix:

```
          tab#1 tab#2 tab#3 (z-index)
  tab#1     1     0    -1
  tab#2     1     1     0
  tab#3     1     1     1
(selected)
```

which I was hoping would show that if you want to show tab#3 then you can set `z-index:1` for all. Similarly if you want to show tab#2 then all tabs apart from the last can have `z-index:1`. In fact the general rule is **set `z-index:1` for all tabs prior to the one you want to show** - this is the first part of the ternary operator (`index < selectedTabIndex ? 1`). The complication comes with the first tab since you want to reverse the natural z-index and move a subsequent tab under a previous one. Essentially the code `(index > selectedTabIndex ? --i : 0)` decrements the z-index for each successive tab and will actually work for more than 3 tabs :-)

So the expected `z-index` result for 5 tabs when you want to show the first tab should be `1 0 -1 -2 -3`. This is all wrapped in the jQuery [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) variant that takes a function callback to change the `z-index` in a succinct manner.

The full code is included but I also made a [**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QxgDr/2/) (3 tabs) and [**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QxgDr/3/) (4 tabs)

#### HTML

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabmenu">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="wrapper-tabs">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab">
            <h1>Tab 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <h1>Tab 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <h1>Tab 3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.tabmenu {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;  
   height: 25px; 
}    
.tabmenu li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: none;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.tabmenu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
.tabmenu li a.selected {
    color:red;
}

.wrapper-tabs{position: relative;float: left;clear:both}
#tab1{position: absolute;z-index:10;left: 0px;top: 0px;background:#ccc;}
#tab2{position: absolute;z-index:20;left: 20px;top: 20px;background:#ff0000;}
#tab3{position: absolute;z-index:30;left: 40px;top: 40px;background:#808080;}

.tabs .tab{clear: both;background:#fff;width:560px;position: relative;top:0px;padding: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:3px 0 5px 0 #BBBBBB;
    -moz-box-shadow:3px 0 5px 0 #BBBBBB;
    box-shadow:3px 0 5px 0 #BBBBBB;min-height:454px;height:auto!important;height:454px;
}
.tab {background:#fff;
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;-moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;border-bottom-left-radius:6px;border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
}
a.mover {
    background: #D8D8D8;
    color: #5F5F5F;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 2px 12px;
    position: absolute;
}
.next-tab {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.prev-tab {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

#### JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.tabmenu a').click(function(e) {
        var selectedTabIndex = parseInt(this.hash.substring(4));

        $('ul.tabmenu a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var i = 0;
        $('.tab').css('z-index', function(index) {
            return index < selectedTabIndex ? 1 : (index > selectedTabIndex ? --i : 0);
        });

        // add selected tab to hash
        window.location.hash = this.hash.replace(/\d$/, selectedTabIndex);

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    var lastTabIndex = $('.tab').length - 1;
    $('.tab').each(function(i) {
        if (i != lastTabIndex) {
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='next-tab mover'>Next Tab &#187;</a>");
        }
        if (i != 0) {
            $(this).append("<a href='#' class='prev-tab mover'>&#171; Prev Tab</a>");
        }
    });

    var tabMenu = $('.tabmenu li');

    $('.next-tab, .prev-tab').click(function() {
        var newTabIndex = $(this).hasClass('next-tab') ? 1 : -1;
        tabMenu.find('a[href="#tab' + (parseInt($(this).closest('div').attr('id').substring(3)) + newTabIndex) + '"]').trigger('click');
    });

    // for page load check for hash else show :first
    var tab = window.location.hash.length > 0 ? window.location.hash : '#tab1';
    $('ul.tabmenu a[href="' + tab + '"]').addClass('active').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: any chance to make the .tabmenu li width a z-index too? 
my design it's quite tricky, and the "li" needs the same z-index of the tab. http://jsfiddle.net/QxgDr/5/

Comment: I hope you can can help me with this... too

Comment: above you can find the screenshot, so you can have a better idea

Comment: Heh, I was about to ask for a screenshot :-) To be honest, you might be better off asking a new question for this (as I can't spare any time right now). It will also get a lot more exposure being a new question. If you mention this question, explain where you got to so far and what you want next, link my 3 tab fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QxgDr/2/ and add that screenshot you should hopefully get an answer

Answer (score 4):

That jQuery seems fine to me, maybe debug some more? Or try something like:

```
$("a:not(:first):not(:last)").css('z-index', '90');
```

Answer (score 2):

try `:first-child` and `:last-child`

Comment: `:first-child` and `:last-child` are CSS pseudos and this syntax doesn't exist in jQuery/Sizzle AFAIK. What should DD77 do, write or modify exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
$('a').not('li:first, li:last').css('z-index', '90');
```

Answer (score 1):

All your answer's are far more complex than they need to be to get not first working.

Remember later applied css rules trump earlier applied css rules except when !important is applied.

If you want to achieve the same as :not(:first-child)
Then:

1. Apply the rule to all elements of that.

Example:

```
ul > li {
 background-color:red;
}
```

1. Apply the contradicting rule to the :first-child which does work.

   ul > li:first-child {
    background-color:transparent;
   }

Unlike all of the comments above.  This DOES NOT require jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Either your HTML you working on is wrong. Or you are executing the code before the anchor tag loaded.
http://jsfiddle.net/pBpe5/