# Jquery Tabs and navigation  z-index positioned

Tags: jquery, z-index, jquery-tabs

![enter image description here][1]On my two demo and screenshot, you can understand that so far I got it working, but I need a bit of more help. The tab **3** needs to be in z-index, and the tab **2** should be just be on top of the content number 2.
I hope it's easy to understand.

http://jsfiddle.net/QxgDr/2/

or better example the nav in position absolute:

http://jsfiddle.net/QxgDr/12/

Comment: Some background to this question can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975723/jquery-not-first-or-last/9983096

Comment: @andyb could you help me with the navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid `z-index` will only work consistently between siblings, not cousins. The tabs should be siblings of the pages to achieve that. You can make the pages themselves part of the `<li>`'s as well, which while solving the problem would also improve semantics. Then you should only handle `<li>`'s `z-index` and profit!

EDIT:

```
<ul id="tabs">
    <li id="tab_1">
        <figure><img alt="..."></figure>
        <article>...</article>
    </li>    
    <li id="tab_2">
        <figure><img alt="..."></figure>
        <article>...</article>
    </li>
    <li id="tab_3">
        <figure><img alt="..."></figure>
        <article>...</article>
    </li>
</ul>
```

From here just position the `figures` where you like (you can even add `z-index:1` to have them stack over the `<articles>`), and work with the `<li>`'s as you did with the tabs.

Comment: Not really, but think of your individual nav links as headers for each article. No JS and no CSS would show a Wikipedia style layout. Applying some of the magic, you should be able to stack them using `position: absolute` and swapping them width `z-index`. Mostly like you're already doing. Keep it up!

Comment: thanks for your help, would be nice if you could help me at least with the navigation?

Comment: thanks, and what about jquery? do I need the code? or it's pure css?

Comment: Mostly CSS. jQuery just needs to set the proper `z-index` (or class) on `figure` click to stack forth or back. You already did that. Also, a vote would be appreciated ;-)

Comment: ok, I'll give a try.... thanks. would be much appreciated if you could put it into fiddle.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9687/discussion-between-dd77-and-keystorm)